# How can I specify certain keyboard shortcuts for certain keyboard layouts

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've searched all over Ubuntu 16.04 and the web but cannot find a way to specify a keyboard shortcut to switch to a certain layout.

The default is that one keyboard shortcut switches between layouts, but I don't want that.

I would like, for example, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to be for English and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>  for Persian, so I can be sure when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> it is certainly on English layout and when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> it's certainly on Persian layout.

Thanks in advance.